# Android Wearable.API is deprecated. What should I use instead?

Tags: android

I'm using the following:

```
GoogleApiClient mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi( Wearable.API )
...
```

Since Wearable.API is deprecated? What is the appropriate replacement?

Comment: did you find any solution for that ?

Comment: I haven't. I am still using the deprecated. (Lazy)

Answer (score 0):

I found answer here:
https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/migrate-to-googleapi

Migrate Wear apps to GoogleApi
Starting with version 11.8.0 of Google Play services, Wear OS apps should migrate away from the GoogleApiClient class and instead use client objects that are based on the GoogleApi class.

Use of GoogleApi makes it easier to set up asynchronous operations. For example, as described in the introduction to the Tasks API, you can obtain a Task object instead of a PendingResult object.

Answer (score -1):

I found something nice which is helpful

```
private class StartWearableActivityTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    final String key;

    public StartWearableActivityTask(String msg){
        key = msg;
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {
        Collection<String> nodes = getNodes();
        for (String node : nodes) {
            sendStartActivityMessage(node,key);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

@WorkerThread
private Collection<String> getNodes() {
    HashSet<String> results = new HashSet<>();

    Task<List<Node>> nodeListTask =
            Wearable.getNodeClient(getApplicationContext()).getConnectedNodes();

    try {
        // Block on a task and get the result synchronously (because this is on a background
        // thread).
        List<Node> nodes = Tasks.await(nodeListTask);

        for (Node node : nodes) {
            results.add(node.getId());

        }

    } catch (ExecutionException exception) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Task failed: " + exception);

    } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Interrupt occurred: " + exception);
    }

    return results;
}

@WorkerThread
private void sendStartActivityMessage(String node,String event) {

    Task<Integer> sendMessageTask =
            Wearable.getMessageClient(this).sendMessage(node, event, new byte[0]);

    try {
        // Block on a task and get the result synchronously (because this is on a background
        // thread).
        Integer result = Tasks.await(sendMessageTask);


    } catch (ExecutionException exception) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Task failed: " + exception);

    } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Interrupt occurred: " + exception);
    }
}
```

Comment: Some explanation?